# Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null when testing in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to create a base class that contains common logic between multiple AWS Lambdas. However, my test fails with:

```
 Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

I tried to create a base handler like this:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { Logger } from '..';

export abstract class BaseHandler<T extends APIGatewayEvent> {

    abstract process(event: T, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>;

    public handle = async (event: T, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
        Logger.debug(`Received event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
        Logger.debug(`Received context: ${JSON.stringify(context)}`);
        try {
            const result: APIGatewayProxyResult = await this.process(event, context);
            Logger.debug(`Returning response: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
            return result;
        } catch (e) {
            Logger.error(`Caught error in handler: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
            const errorResponse: APIGatewayProxyResult = {
                statusCode: statusCode,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    code: e.statusCode,
                    message: e.message
                })
            };
            return errorResponse;
        }
    };
}

module.exports.BaseHandler;
```

And then a specific lambda that inherits this:

```
import { BaseHandler } from '../base-handler.abstract.class';
import { APIGatewayProxyResult, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { InheritedLambdaRequest } from '../types/inherited-lambda-request.type';


class InheritedLambda extends BaseHandler<InheritedLambdaRequest> {
    constructor() { 
        super();
    }
    public process = async (event: InheritedLambdaRequest, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
        //business logic
    }
}
export const handler = new InheritedLambda();
export const inheritedLambda = handler.process;
```

However, my jest test fails:

```
import { inheritedLambda } from './inherited-lambda';

describe('Handle Inherited Lambda', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });
    it('should return 204', (done) => {
        inheritedLambda(request, undefined).then((result) => {
            expect(result.statusCode).toEqual(204);
            expect(result.body).toEqual('');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This can be caused by circular dependencies.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, without circular dependencies